# WinForms custom control, DoubleBuffered, read that buffer?

Tags: c#, winforms

When creating a custom control, `DoubleBuffered` seems to be doing all the work for me, instead of my manually creating a bitmap. but is it possible to read from the buffer that `DoubleBuffered` is using?

Comment: See if you can manage it by using Bitmap object. Covert Graphics object into Bitmap, manipulate in Bitmap and then covert back into Graphics object.  e.g. Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, myGraphics);

Comment: _Convert Graphics object into Bitmap_ This is a misleading expression. You can only associate a Bitmap to a Graphics object; then anything it draws will be drawn into the Bitmap.

Comment: No that buffer can't be read other than by having it copied to a Bitmap by control.DrawToBitmap

Comment: The internal `BufferedGraphicsContext` class (which allocates a Control's  [BufferedGraphics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bufferedgraphics) object) is *maintained* by a  [BufferedGraphicsManager](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/BufferedGraphicsManager.cs,26) object. The references to these objects are private and these classes are sealed. So, only through reflection. But you can create and handle your own BufferedGraphics objects, when needed.